# Insert Partial Values from another table in Sql , and others manually

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

Before anyone gives me code of inserting values from other table to my table , i want to clearify i need partial values ...

I mean like i am making Admission Module in which after Student is admitted , from FeeDetail table details of payment are taken using his Class and his details ie scholarId etc from Input form . and an unpaid Invoice/FeeSlip is created.

I tried this code but does not works..

```
Insert into FeePayment(FeeID,TutionFees,LibraryFees,UniversityDevelopmentFees,UniversityStudentWelfareFees,SecurityDeposit,OtherFees,TotalFees,DueFees,FeePaymentID,ScholarNo,Class,TotalPaid)values((select FeeID,TutionFees,LibraryFees,UniversityDevelopmentFees,UniversityStudentWelfareFees,SecurityDeposit,OtherFees,TotalFees,TotalFees from FeesDetails where class='FYBCA'),'FD0001','ST101','FYBCA',0);
```

Error i get From Sql is

`Error while executing SQL query: 5 values for 13 columns`(Checked from Sql not Java)

Comment: "I tried this code but does not works" is not very detailed. Does nothing happen? Do you get an error message? Does something different happen than what you expected, and if yes, what?

Comment: Well i get error Error while executing SQL query: 5 values for 13 columns(Checked from Sql not Java)

Comment: So, your select is only returning 5 columns so give just the five colums you want the data to go into in your insert clause.

Comment: Well i require value for 13 coloums , 4 i am providing Manually and for other 9 i have given 9 coloums

Comment: "where class='FYBCA','FD0001','ST101','FYBCA',0" looks very weird

Comment: as I understand it, these 4 values currently belong to the subquery - is that what you wanted?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 4 values i am providing and for rest 9 i am providing an select Query to fetch from other table

Comment: @TilmanHausherr correct that its where class='FYBCA'),'FD0001','ST101','FYBCA',0"

Comment: FYBCA is the condition n rest 4 are values i am providing for remaining 4 fields

Answer (score 0):

At first keep all constant values from select query itself('FD0001','ST101','FYBCA',0). And then remove "values()" keyword. This should be omitted since you may have to insert as many records as the sub query returns.

The final query would be:

```
Insert into FeePayment(FeeID,TutionFees,LibraryFees,UniversityDevelopmentFees,UniversityStudentWelfareFees,SecurityDeposit,OtherFees,TotalFees,DueFees,FeePaymentID,ScholarNo,Class,TotalPaid) select FeeID,TutionFees,LibraryFees,UniversityDevelopmentFees,UniversityStudentWelfareFees,SecurityDeposit,OtherFees,TotalFees,TotalFees,'FD0001','ST101','FYBCA',0 from FeesDetails where class='FYBCA';
```

Comment: I am getting Syntax error near Select when executing this statement

Comment: see here: https://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/sql-server-insert-into-with-subquery/

Comment: i.e. leave out the "values" stuff. But take care that the fields match.

Comment: According to this link i will have to pass 9 sub statements for 9 values , cant it be done by 1 single statement?

Comment: That's not the way I understand it. You just enter insert into FeePayment (....) select .... from ... where ... .

Comment: Read it properly about values , but its required as orignal table has 20 fields .

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I understood that but its only possible if we are inserting values for all coloums , but in FeePayment there are 19 fields and i m passing to only 13 so i require to use Values .

Comment: A select can return fixed values. For example, "select FeeId, 3, 4, 5 from FeePayment" is a valid query that will deliver four columns. That is the trick that hemanth uses.

Comment: Can you try this query first: `select FeeID,TutionFees,LibraryFees,UniversityDevelopmentFees,UniversityStudentWelfareFees,SecurityDeposit,OtherFees,TotalFees,TotalFees,'FD0001','ST101','FYBCA',0 from FeesDetails where class='FYBCA';`

Comment: Then what is the syntax error you are getting when executes complete query? You may have to take care of datatypes!

Comment: Error is [16:55:06] Error while executing SQL query: near "select": syntax error

Comment: @hemanth you made the same error in your response as the one described in my link (see the text in red there). Remove "values(" and the ")" at the end.

Comment: @hemanth make changes in answer so i can mark it as best answer

Comment: @hemanth yes please do so and explain that "values" is not to be used. Although if it was a team effort, I'll upvote your response :-)

Comment: btw @TilmanHausherr  u both seem good at sql , can u please see this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964907/jdatechooser-inserting-and-retriving-from-database